# Nesting Editor Templates: Unable to pass model => model to base Editor Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inheritance, mvc-editor-templates

Take the following models as an example:

```cs
namespace MyNamespace.Model
{
    //you can only have two friends for the sake of simplicity in this example :P
    public class Friends{
        public Person NormalFriend { get; set; }
        public Hipster HipsterFriend { get; set; }
    }

    public class Person{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hipster : Person
    {
        public HatType HatPreference { get; set; }
        public int CoolPoints { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Let's say we're trying to add our two friends, a normal friend and a hipster friend:

**Create.cshtml**:

```cshtml
@model MyNamespace.Model.Friends

<div class='container'>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NormalFriend) //uses Person EditorTemplate by convention

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HipsterFriend) //uses Hipster EditorTemplate by convention
</div>
```

**EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml**:

```cshtml
@model MyNamespace.Model.Person

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber)
    </div>
</div>
```

**EditorTemplates/Hipster.cshtml**:

```cshtml
@model MyNamespace.Model.Hipster

@Html.EditorFor(model => model, "Person") // <-- what I've tried and it isn't working

<div class='row'>
    <div class='col'>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CoolPoints)
    </div>
    <div class='col'>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HatPreference)
    </div>
</div>
```

In the `Hipster` EditorTemplate, the code

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model, "Person")
```

should pass the `Hipster` model to the `Person` EditorTemplate so that I don't have to repeat the Templated Code for shared properties (of the base type `Person`).

Currently, the above code just completely ignores the `EditorFor` and only displays the `Hipster` specific properties(ie `CoolPoints` and `HatPreference`).

Alternatively, I *could* change the following code in Create.cshtml:

```cshtml
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NormalFriend) 

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HipsterFriend)
```

to:

```cshtml
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NormalFriend) 

 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HipsterFriend, "Person") //break convention and the idea of nesting     
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HipsterFriend)
```

which will achieve what I want, but it seems wrong that I am unable to do this in the `Hipster` EditorTemplate.

Is my logic flawed on this or am I missing something? I thought it possibly could be disregarding the line in question for fear of recursion but the `templateName` argument should clarify.  This idea of inheriting the base type and nesting works with partials but partials don't handle `ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName`s of complex objects which are necessary for validation.

---

This question is related: [In an Editor Template call another Editor Template with the same Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811717/in-an-editor-template-call-another-editor-template-with-the-same-model) although the solution isn't applicable in my situation. Is there a workaround to nest the views without using partials or is that my only way?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't use a partial in your template?

Comment: AFAIK, partials don't retain parent property information. So you will get duplicate `ids` and `names` and will be unable to differentiate between `NormalFriend` and `HipsterFriend` properties (ie `EditorFor(model => model.Name)` would return something like `<input  id="Name" name="Name" type="text" value="">` rather than `<input  id="HipsterFriend_Name" name="HipsterFriend.Name" type="text" value="">`